# Identify when Application_BeginRequest and Application_EndRequest tie up

Tags: .net, rest

I want to add some logging of how long it takes for a .Net Web Application is taking to process a request.

My idea was to use `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest`, I could check `HttpContext.Current.Request.Path` in `Application_BeginRequest`and log a start-time and when the same `HttpContext.Current.Request.Path` goes through `Application_EndRequest` log the end-time.  But with a busy website I could not guarantee that multiple calls would mess this idea up (a call may come in that takes longer to run than an identical call).

So my question is, is there something that I can check in `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` that ties the calls together, is there some ID or something?  Or is there something more simple that I could be doing?

Comment: You can stuff things into `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

Comment: Each request as an Id as identifier. So why not use It ? If you implement a HTTPModule from IHttpModule, you can make it happens

Comment: So I could generate a unique id in the `BeginRequest`, add it to the `.Items` and then check it in the `EndRequest`

Answer (score 3):

My solution for this was to use `HttpContext.Current.Items` as suggested by ta.speot.is

In `Application_BeginRequest` I  create a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` and call `.Start` on it.

Add the `Stopwatch` to `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

In `Application_EndRequest` retrieve the `Stopwatch` from `HttpContext.Current.Items` and call `.Stop` I can now check `.Elapsed` and that gives me my timings.

When I posted my question I was not aware that `HttpContext.Current.Items` is specific to a call, but I do now - so this provides the solution.